# moving the directory into s3 bucket

Tags: r, amazon-s3, subdirectory

When i try to move my directory using the code below into s3 bucket, i get error as below:
Please help!

```
Error: The specified pathname is not a file: cars
```

Code used

```
library("aws.s3")
lapply(dir(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE), function(filename) {
    put_object(file = "cars", object = "cars", bucket = "bkt1")
})
```

Comment: Do lapply(dir(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE), function(filename) {
    put_object(file = filename, object = "cars", bucket = "bkt1")
}) solve your issue ? You don't pass `filename` anywhere

Comment: solved the issue Thanks!